# Page with iframe doesn't load javascript in webview to samsung devices

Tags: javascript, android, iframe, webview

I opened a page that has a iframe with javascript in webview but don't works in Samsung devices. In others devices works such as Morotola, LG, etc. Why?

The page should be display a form with validation but the "validation code" in javascript doesn't loaded in samsung devices. I'm using the JavascriptEnabled method but don't works.

```
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl(URL);
```

Any a idea?

Thanks

Comment: I solve problems using the Crosswalk - (https://crosswalk-project.org) in my application.